# How to integrate Sales force and Django?

Tags: python, django, salesforce

I have to complete a task below:

I have to implement salesforce integration.  Which include fetching user token from salesforce using OAuth2. Once I have the token I need to fetch the list of Users, Accounts, and Contacts from salesforce and store it in the database.

I need to write the code in Django and not supposed to use any existing third-party salesforce integration app?

Please suggest me resources or algorithm to achieve the solution.

Comment: There is extensive [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) on the Salesforce REST API to get started.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cViU2-xVscA, he has clearly mentioned the steps for creating a *user account and then connected app* creation and then managing our endpoint, and yes the above-mentioned *docs* will not harm.